# Script Scope Access

Tags: php

So, I've been working on a small project, nothing extensive. I've been having trouble understand why a certain function in my anonymous object isn't accessible on my main script.

Alright so my "initializer", or the script to be loaded before any crucial operations, instantiates an anonymous object to be accessed across the entire scope of my project.

```
<?php

    class T_EMPTY {
        public function __call($method, $args) {
            if(isset($this->$method) && is_callable($this->$method)) {
                return call_user_func_array(
                    $this->$method, 
                    $args
                );
            }
        }
    }

    $scope = new T_EMPTY;

    $scope->config = array(
        'path' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
        'loct' => '*'
    );
        set_include_path ( $scope->config['path'] );

    $scope->controller = $scope->service = $scope->service->injector = new T_EMPTY;
        // #    instantiate our empty structures
    $scope->service->injector->inject = function($rsc) {
        global $scope;
        if( is_array( $rsc ) && count( $rsc ) >= 1 ):
            foreach( $rsc as $r ):
                require_once( $scope->config['path'] . '/api/services/' . $r . '.php' );
            endforeach;
        else:
            require_once( $scope->config['path'] . '/api/services/' . $rsc . '.php' );
        endif;
    };
    $scope->service->injector->f = "foobar";
```

The issue standing, is that after importing this into my main script via

```
require_once
```

I cannot access the 'inject' function.

```
global $scope;
$f = & $scope->service->injector;
$f->inject( 'communicator' ); // # function marked undefined
echo $f->f; // element exists
```

The function for whatever reason is undefined, but I can access 'f' without any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$scope->service` doesn't have an `injector` property. Your chained assignment that initializes `$scope->service->injector` isn't doing what you think, because assignments associate from right to left. So

```
$scope->controller = $scope->service = $scope->service->injector = new T_EMPTY;
```

is executed as if it's

```
$temp1 = $scope->service->injector = new T_EMPTY;
$temp2 = $scope->service = $temp1;
$scope->controller = $temp2;
```

The assignment to `$scope->service` overwrites the `$scope->service` object that was created implicitly by the assignment to `$scope->service->injector` with the new `T_EMPTY` instance, and this doesn't have an `injector` property.

The other problem with the chained assignment is that you're setting them all to the **same** `T_EMPTY` instance (objects aren't copied when they're assigned, like arrays are), which is probably not what you wanted. Change that line to:

```
$scope->controller = new T_EMPTY;
$scope->service = new T_EMPTY;
$scope->service->injector = new T_EMPTY;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Dearly noted for the future, I didn't quite understand the process of the chained operation.